# Change instance values after capture change with Django Signals

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-signals

I have a model `Course` that have a ManyToMany relation with my `CustomUser` model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(_('User Name'), max_length=150, unique=True)
    # and a lot of other fields and stuff


class Course(models.Model):
    enrolled_users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="enrolls", blank=True)
    previous_enrolled_users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="previous_enrolls", blank=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(_("Course Name"), max_length=200)
```

What I'm trying to implement is that whenever a user finishes a course (and so the user is removed from `enrolled_users`), my application stores this user in `previous_enrolled_users`, so I can know the users that were previously enrolled at that course.

I've implement a `m2m_changed` signal listening like this:

```
def listen_m2mchange(sender, instance, model, pk_set, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'pre_remove':
        # I'm trying to guess what to do

m2m_changed.connect(listen_m2mchange, sender=Course.enrolled_users.through)
```

With that, whenever I remove a user from a course, Django signals the `m2m_changed` and I capture that signal. I know that `instance` is the instance of the `Course` class and that `model` is the instance of that `CustomUser` class I'm removing. What I could not guess is how, using the instance of `Course` class, I can add the `CustomUser` in the previous_enrolled_users. Any help will be very appreciated.

EDIT 01:

Reading a lot of the docs, I get that what I want is doing this everytime `model` is removed from `enrolled_users`:

```
instance.previous_enrolled_users.add(model)
```

But when I do it, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'core.models.CustomUser'>.
```

Comment: Haven't tried this, but from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) you can use the `pk_set` to determine which pks are to be removed.

Comment: @bdbd I know that. What I want, however, is to change the value of `previous_enrolled_users`, to include the value I've removed from `enrolled_users`.

Comment: Yes so in the signal handler for `pre_remove` (or even `post_remove`), you will get the pk of the `CustomUser` you just removed from `enrolled_users`. You then should be able to use that same pk to add to `previous_enrolled_users`?

Comment: @bdbd Yes but, how? I really don't know how using `instance` and `model` I can achieve it. I think that is something like this: `instance.previous_enrolled_users.insert_value(model)`. I don't know what method I should use considering I have a instance of the model `Course`.

Comment: Yes I think you are in the right direction. You just need to use [m2m add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) on the `pk_set`. Since you get the pks that got removed, you can use the same to add to the other field,  so: `instance.previous_enrolled_users.add(pk_set)`

Comment: afaik, the `m2m_changed` won't have the `CustomUser` ***"instance"***, as you wished for. IMO, it is better to do the operation (removal and adding of `CustomUser` instance) where both instances are available - may at the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def listen_enrolled_users_m2mchange(sender, instance, model, pk_set, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_remove':
        instance.previous_enrolled_users.add(*pk_set)

m2m_changed.connect(listen_enrolled_users_m2mchange, sender=Course.enrolled_users.through)
```

`pk_set` here will be a set of primary keys that were involved in the changes of `enrolled_users` field in `Course`. That means when the action is `post_remove`, all the removed `CustomUser` primary keys will be passed in the `pk_set` kwarg.

This then means that when the signal kicks in for the changes on `enrolled_users` of `Course`, we can check if the action is a remove. In that case, the same `pk_set` we received that are removed from `enrolled_users` can be directly added to  `previous_enrolled_users`.

Answer (score -1):

this is models.py I used to recreate the issue:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where username is unique identifiers
    able to add more fields to Django basic User model.
    """

    def create_user(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('The username must be set'))
        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_staffuser(self, username, first_name, last_name,  password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have a password")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("User must have a first name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("User must have a last name")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(username)
        )
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.set_password(password)  # change password to hash
        user.is_admin = False
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(_('User Name'), max_length=150, unique=True)
    # and a lot of other fields and stuff
    objects = CustomUserManager()


class Course(models.Model):
    enrolled_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomUser, blank=True)
    previous_enrolled_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomUser, related_name="previous_enrolls", blank=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(_("Course Name"), max_length=200)


def listen_m2mchange(sender, **kwargs):
    pass

m2m_changed.connect(listen_m2mchange, sender=Course.enrolled_users.through)
```

useful code in Django shell:

```
In [1]: from hello.models import CustomUser, Course

In [2]: U3 = CustomUser.objects.create(username='test3', user_name='tes 
   ...: t3', email='test3@g.com')

In [3]: U3 = CustomUser.objects.create(username='test4', user_name='tes 
   ...: t4', email='test4@g.com')
In [4]: C = Course.objects.create(course_name='some course3')
In [5]: C.enrolled_users.add(U3)
In [6]: C.enrolled_users.get()
Out[6]: <CustomUser: test4>
In [7]: C.enrolled_users.remove(U3) # removes the user from the set
```

I hope this was useful.

Comment: I think the question is about how would you access the variable named ***`U3`*** in your ***`listen_m2mchange(...)`*** signal handler when someone calls **`C.enrolled_users.remove(U3)`**?